# I am having trouble booting 12.04 keyboard and little man in circle appears and then nothing

Tags: boot-failure

I have a new system (ASUS 990FX mother board, 2 western dig drives, 32 gb memory, an ASUS nvidia video card (GeForce GTX560), and an ASUS DVD Burner (24B1ST)) I am struggling to get the 12.04 cd to work.  I have been able to see the little man inside a circle and a graphic of a keyboard? with an == sign between them.

Is this is a clue?  What does it mean?  After that the mauve screen with keyboard and little man in circle goes away.  I get a dark background and underline cursor... even hear some work being done reading the rom.... but nothing appears on the screen.

I haven't even got to the point where the graphic card is displaying improperly... it is just not displaying anything.

If any kind soul has an idea about how to proceed, I am all ears.  BTW, I have posted the issue to ASUS... waiting for reply.

Comment: another data point.  I got a copy of win7 and tried to boot with it as well.  It loads up to a point where it asks for drivers for the sata (these are seen in the bios, btw).  I downloaded the latest, but for some reason, it can't load them... at least off the usb mem drive.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, I installed a new motherboard which has USB 3. I know it sounds weird but when i took it out of the usb 3 and put into usb 2 slot it worked perfectly fine.

Check if you are using USB 3 slot, I'm not sure why that affects it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to re-burn the .iso onto the disk again? The burning process could have corrupted parts of the .iso. Have you tried re-downloading the .iso and burning it again? Have you ever run Ubuntu on your system? Have you checked to see if your hardware is compatible [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/)?

Comment: I have downloaded several times.. burning on different media (dvd and cdrom).  I have used the cdrom to launch ubuntu on a different system.  That seems to work.  As to the compatibility, none of my systems that run ubuntu are on that list.

Comment: Ok, have you tried "burning" it to a flash drive then? If it worked on another system, I wonder about your CD rom drive. Also, if that doesn't work, temporarily try WUBI to see if that works.

Comment: I mounted the iso image on a 11.04 system and used the startup disk creator.  I have not been able to get that to work as a boot device.

Comment: Ohh, the startup disk creator was NOT meant to burn .isos of a newer version. Use Brasero Disk Burner to burn the .iso, or use a Windows .iso burner if you don't have Brasero. If that does not work, try running a VM of Ubuntu just to see if it initializes

Comment: I will give it a try.  I held the shift key down and got the menu ... I am running the memory test now.  I will try your suggestion tomorrow.  Thanks for sticking with me on this.

Comment: Honestly, it's no problem. I have had errors before with ubuntu, and there is always someone willing to help. I just thought I'd return the favor. On a more related note, did your manufacturer say that it can run Ubuntu (for instance: my dell Inspiron came with the option to dual-boot Ubuntu with windows 7 and it had a specific page in the manual. I had to upgrade it though, so I just did a fresh install)?

Comment: asus replied.  they claim they don't support it.  I have tried windows 7 now.  It doesn't install either.  :-|

Comment: Ok, Windows 7 SHOULD install no matter what as Ubuntu doesn't touch the BIOS AFAIK. Have you tried loading a Windows 7 recover disk -> command prompt -> "bootrec.exe /Fix Boot" and "bootrec.exe /FixMbr" or is your entire HDD been erased?

Comment: haven't tried that.  I have been using a full (as opposed to upgrade) product cd.  It gets to the point where it wants to load onto one of the hard drives but can't find any.  It offers a button that will allow you to load drivers.  I am trying to load the drivers.

Comment: I made a small amt of progress in that until this evening, it just wouldn't do anything.  I reread the mobo manual and it suggested that a certain driver must be installed first... the JMBX36 controller driver.

Comment: I tried this one as opposed to the AHCI drivers they have and actually got a disk to show in the result box... with the admonition that it can't install to that disk (it shows 0 bytes unallocated space) with a total size of 0.  The other disk doesn't show... so I suspect it is as you surmise... the disks do not have any mbr ... I will try your idea.  I think I can create a recover cd on one of our boxes and use it here.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: The asus tech suggested trying the drives in another box, which I did.  Both of them failed to "IDENTIFY" at post time.  RMA completed and new drives from other company and manufacturer on way, including a solid state model.

Answer (score 0):

The little man icon tells you that you can press a key in order to see a menu with boot options. It might be possible to obtain said menu by keeping shift down even before that icon appears. In the menu, you might be able to select some kind of verbose text mode, and doing so actually see what's going wrong.

Comment: I will give this a try.